# Subtracting two Ieee754 numbers and I am not getting the correct result

Tags: floating-point, binary, subtraction, ieee-754

I am currently writing a Compiler to just test my programing ability and my target architecture doesn't have a Floating Point Unit. To account for this I am adding functions to my standard library to handle floating point calculations with Bitwise operations. All the floating point calculations are 32 bits. With 1 sign bit, 8 bits for the exponent, and 23 bits for the Mantissa. Detailed below are all the steps utilized for the subtraction operation.

As a note currently the code I have in the Standard Library works for numbers of the same sign and even works for some circumstances of numbers with different signs.

The test case I have that is failing is associated with the following subtraction operation:

50.0 - 92.0 = -42.0

As stated above the operation I am trying to solve is 50.0 - 92.0 which should equal -42.0.

Step one should be to convert both the numbers into binary:

The Converted numbers are as followed...

```
        Sign  Exp      Mantissa                Binary Scientific Notation
  50.0 = 0|10000100|10010000000000000000000 = 1.10010000000000000000000x2^5
  92.0 = 0|10000101|01110000000000000000000 = 1.01110000000000000000000x2^6
```

Step two is to raise the exponent of the 50.0 so that the exponent 5 becomes a 6. Therefor we will need to shift the bits 1 place to the right to account for the increase in the exponent.

```
1.10010000000000000000000x2^5 becomes 0.11001000000000000000000x2^6
```

Step three is to get the twos compliment of the 2nd value because we are subtracting 92.0 not adding.

```
1.01110000000000000000000x2^6 inverted is 0.10001111111111111111111x2^6
0.10001111111111111111111x2^6 + 1 is 0.10010000000000000000000x2^6
```

The final step is to add the Mantissas together

```
  0.11001000000000000000000x2^6
+ 0.10010000000000000000000x2^6
_______________________________
  1.01011000000000000000000x2^6
```

Now this final bit is where I get a bit confused because the final result of -42 in ieee754 format is

```
       Sign Exp          Mantissa
-42.0 = 1|10000100|01010000000000000000000
```

And obviously the Mantissa

```
01010000000000000000000 is not
01011000000000000000000
```

Does anyone have some insight as to what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: You’re writing a compiler but the question doesn’t really have anything to do with [tag:compiler-construction].

Comment: To subtract floating point numbers (manually), first check if the result will be positive or negative by checking which number is bigger. Then get the absolute value by subtracting the smaller from the larger value (after shifting the exponent), then normalize the result. But honestly, search if someone already implemented a soft-float library for your target architecture. There are a lot of border-cases you need to consider when doing floating point math manually.

Answer (score 2):

You have not used enough bits to handle two’s complement correctly, and you have not handled a negative result.

In complementing the positive 1.01110000000000000000000<sub>2</sub>×2<sup>6</sup>, you got 0.10010000000000000000000<sub>2</sub>×2<sup>6</sup>. The result should be a negative number, but a leading 0 in two’s complement indicates a positive number. In other words, your complement operation overflowed the format.

If you prefix a leading 0 and then complement, you will have 10.10010000000000000000000<sub>2</sub>×2<sup>6</sup>, and you will add this to 00.11001000000000000000000<sub>2</sub>×2<sup>6</sup>, which has also had a 0 prefixed. Then the sum is 11.01011000000000000000000<sub>2</sub>×2<sup>6</sup>.

The leading bit is 1, indicating the result is negative. So you can complement it again to see the absolute value, 00.101010000000000000000002×2<sup>6</sup>, meaning the result is −00.101010000000000000000002×2<sup>6</sup>.

Finally, you normalize this to −1.010100000000000000000002×2<sup>5</sup>, which is −42.

## Notes

This explanation is not an endorsement of using two’s complement. Implementing a direct subtractor may be preferred.

“Significand” is the preferred term for the fraction part of a floating-point number. “Mantissa” is an old term for the fraction part of a logarithm. Significands are linear (if the number increases by a factor of 1.2, the significand increases by a factor of 1.2, unless an exponent threshold is crossed), whereas mantissas are logarithmic (adding to the mantissa multiplies the value represented).